# error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call (swift)

Tags: swift, parameters, arguments

I am trying to call a function in `GameScene.swift` from `GameViewController.swift`, but whatever I tried, I keep getting the "missing argument for parameter #1 in call" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//GameViewController.swift file

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation


class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{


var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var scene:GameScene!



//This function gives the error:
func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){ 
    scene.swipedRight1() //error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)

    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    var bgMusicURL:NSURL=NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic",withExtension:"mp3")!
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error:nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    println("music playing")
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Gamescene.swift file

```
import SpriteKit



class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var player:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoder not supported")
}

override init(size:CGSize) {
    super.init(size:size)
   anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:1.0)

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg3")

   background.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
   background.anchorPoint=CGPoint(x:0,y:1.0)

     addChild(background)

    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"kikker1")

    player.xScale = 0.22
   player.yScale = 0.22

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

   player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, -610)
    addChild(player)

    println("klaar")
    println(player.position)
}


//This is the function I am trying to call
  func swipedRight1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    println("swipe right")

}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

Comment: It would be good to know which function is having the problem, and which one you are trying to call

Comment: Thanks, added in code(see //)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function swipedRight1(sender : ...) requires one parameter of type sender so may be you should try to provide the perimeter like this:

```
 func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){ 
 scene.swipedRight1(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you are trying to call has this signature:

```
func swipedRight1(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
```

but you are calling it with no parameters:

```
scene.swipedRight1()
```

just pass it the expected parameter, which in this case it's the same sender you have in the calling method:

```
scene.swipedRight1(sender)
```